Google Sheets. Search exact string (two iterations maximum) by rows with conditions
I have a table with tasks assigned to several persons. Every person have a inicial and ended date for that task. If the final date is empty means that currently is being carried out by that person.
I need generate other table that contains the task that is being carried out by person. I leave a example (the yellow table is the one to be filled automatically).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ehmIMNdsvpAI5Mi_kFBahxTkWfnEx8-6qDn04z-anLg/edit?usp=sharing
I have tried with find/search functions but I has been impossible achieved, maybe it's no possible (perhaps with QUERY?).
Then, I have tried filter the dates rows with odd elements (that mean the task it have not filled out yet). But from there, I don't know obtain the index of the name cell. And even if I succeeded, neither I know how search two iterations of the name for the cases that have two tasks assigned.
I don't know if it is possible do it with functions or you occur other manner.

you've shared a sample sheet in view only mode and you have also disabled the ability to make a copy. Next time please share the sheet in EDIT mode or at least give us the ability to make a copy so we don't have to waste our time manually rebuilding your data from scratch.

You're right. I had not thought about it. Sorry. Theoretically now you can copy the file. If not, let me know.

EDIT: Formula that works with arrays and accepts open-ended ranges
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
     tasks;{'Tasks 1-6'!B4:B;'Task 7-9'!B5:B};table;{'Tasks 1-6'!C4:J;'Task 7-9'!C5:J};r;ROWS(table);c;COLUMNS(table);
     MAP(B4:B8;LAMBDA(name;IFERROR(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";1;
        IF((table=name)*
             (IFNA(VSTACK(CHOOSEROWS(table;SEQUENCE(r-1;1;2));))<>"")*
               (IFNA(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(VSTACK(CHOOSEROWS(table;SEQUENCE(r-1;1;2)););SEQUENCE(c-1;1;2));))="");
           tasks;));","))))))


Here's a possible solution:
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAP(L4:L8,LAMBDA(name,IFERROR(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,
    IF((C4:J15=name)*(OFFSET(C4:J15,1,0)<>"")*(OFFSET(C4:J15,1,1)=""),B4:B15,)),",")))))



It works perfectly. Thank you so much. The last doubt. What would it be like if there were other tables with news tasks for the same people (with the same conditions)? I have edited the shared example file for understanding.

you can simply expand the ranges: C4:J15 becomes C4:J23, B4:B15 becomes B4:B23

And if the second table is separately in another sheet?

I have edit the example with a table by sheet.

I have tried concatenated the tables with {Sheet1!Range; Sheet2!Range}, but I don't know why doesn't work. Maybe why it doesn't maintain the combine cells?

can you provide edit access to th  sheet?

Done, now you can edit the sheet.
